# Read CSV file with Python function

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write my read/write function to a csv, but it can't return any value.

I'm reading from a CSV, replacing the " ; " in the second column with " " and performing and saving the csv already handled.

But for some reason it doesn't save my csv, is my function wrong?

I'm starting out in the Python world, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

```
import pandas as pd

header_col = ['col0','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9']
df = pd.read_csv('myfile_<date>.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", sep=';', names=header_col, header=None)

def file_load(df):
    df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(';',' ') 
    df.drop(columns=['col8'], inplace=True)
    df.drop(columns=['col9'], inplace=True)
    
    return df

def save_file(dataframe):
    df = dataframe
    df.to_csv('myfile_<date>_treat.csv' ,sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: Why do you need `df = dataframe`? Just use `dataframe.to_csv`

Comment: Just to make interpretation easier @Barmar

Comment: It didn't work for me....

Comment: Show how you're calling the functions.

Comment: I can modify it by removing the dataframe, can you tell me @Barmar why it passes without error and doesn't save my file? :(

Comment: I'm trying this way even though it's above

Comment: You never call `file_load` or `save_file` above.

Comment: And how should it look? I'm really having a hard time understanding, sorry

Comment: `file_load(df)` and then `save_file(df)`

Comment: Since you're reading the cover file with `;` as delimiter, there won't be any semi colons in the read datagrams. Replacing semicolon won't work.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN Unless they're escaped.

Comment: In my second column there is " ; " in the data, for example: col1 = Windows ; Firefox 00191, US

Comment: Is your data comma separated or semicolon separated? In any case, you should provide a sample input and sample output.

Comment: I just fixed the delimiter. It seems that the functions are failing to talk to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def file_load(df):
    df['col1'] = str(df['col1']).replace(';',' ') 
    df.drop(columns=['col8'], inplace=True)
    df.drop(columns=['col9'], inplace=True)
    return df

def save_file(dataframe):
    df = dataframe
    df.to_csv('myfile_<date>_treat.csv' ,sep=',', encoding='utf-8', 
    index=False)


def main():
    header_col= 
    ['col0','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9']
    df = pd.read_csv('myfile_<date>.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", sep=';', 
    names=header_col, header=None)

    df1 = file_load(df)
    save_file(df1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```